# How to disable automatic escaping of quotes - BASH

Tags: bash, console

I have this test code in my bash file:

```
gtest() {
    echo 'hello'
}

bind '"\C-g\C-x": "$(gtest)\e\C-e"'
```

When I start typing something like `vim "`, and then press <kbd>C-g</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd>, I get `vim hello` instead of `vim "hello`.

If I type `vim """sometext` and then press <kbd>C-g</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd>, I get `vim sometexthello` instead of `vim """sometexthello`.

Is there a way to retain the quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bind '"\C-g\C-x": "\C-u$(gtest)\e\C-e\C-a\C-y\C-e"'
```

The problem was that `\e\C-e` evaluates the line. It's good for executing `$(gtest)`, yet it can obviously mess with `"` chars.

The trick is to save the line with `C-u`, evaluate only `$(gtest)`, place the cursor at the beginning (`C-a`), restore saved line (`C-y`) and finally place the cursor at the end (`C-e`).

Comment: +1 OMG, thank you very much, I have been trying a bunch of stuff ..:) Again, thank you mate.